# Twitter login completed with an error

Tags: android, twitter

I'm currently trying to login with twitter in my app. I followed the Twitter and Fabric tutorial about login but i'm getting this error.

```
Authorization completed with an error
                                                           com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:97)
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:161)
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:131)
```

Activity:

```
   TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

    twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
            TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
            String token = authToken.token;
            String secret = authToken.secret;
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi MGDiez did you got any work around for this issue

Comment: Make sure your consumerKey and consumerSecret are ok!